# Case studies to help sell UCD

Tags: ucd, use-cases

I'm looking for some nice simple stats and references to help convince potential clients of the value of UCD. Real-life case studies you can explain in one line I suppose.

One of my favourites is of course UIE's [$300 Million button](http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button/).

What are your favourites?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was asked to provide some UCD case studies at work, preferrably those from global companies. My colleagues found these interesting:

**The Cost of Frustration**
http://www.uie.com/articles/cost_of_frustration/

**Gradual Engagement Boosts Twitter Sign-Ups by 29%**
http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1128

**Case Study: Fewer Input Fields Increases Conversions**
http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?910

**Google**
Recruiting user participants for testing - http://blogs.zdnet.com/micro-markets/?p=472

**Facebook**
Gathering user feedback before implementing a new design change - http://user-vision.blogspot.com/2008/07/new-facebook-usability-research-on.html

**Amazon**
Letting their users decide - http://www.uie.com/articles/magicbehindamazon/

**Tripadvisor**
“Since joining in 2004, Petersen has overseen tremendous growth of site traffic, revenue, content and membership, *including driving user involvement* through the launch of rich product offerings such as maps, video, personalization and intra-member email” - http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/PressCenter-c5-Our_Team.html

**Expedia** 
“The usability testing course was delivered at a comfortable pace and in a group small enough to benefit all levels of experience. Thanks for a very enjoyable course!

Graham Farrugia, Expedia.co.uk”

**Microsoft - Halo 3**
http://www.wired.com/gaming/virtualworlds/magazine/15-09/ff_halo?currentPage=all

The button one is my favourite though :-)

Comment: Some great finds there. Covers a bit of all areas. But yes, the $300 Million Button case study pretty much sums it all up!

Comment: The nice thing about the $300 Million Button case study is its simple, and is a nice description of 'real user' behaviour.

Comment: +1 *Great answer!* Especially the Amtrack example -- stunning and irresistible to management. Thanks!

Comment: They are all good examples for market-driven products but how about bespoke projects?

Answer (score 8):

IBM: "Every dollar invested in ease of use returns $10 to $100."

source: Design @ IBM > Design > User Centred Design

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/ucd/ucd.html

Answer (score 4):

A recent one I've found very interesting (and have mentioned to other clients) is the Waitrose redesign. Huge amount of bad responses from users, online message boards flooded with negative comments, twitter awash with complaints. All this could have been avoided (or at least reduced) by considering the Users first rather than the brand and the style.

There are a couple of articles about this on eConsultancy:

[new waitrose website panned by users](http://econsultancy.com/uk/blog/7315-new-waitrose-website-panned-by-users)

[Waitrose redesign where does it go wrong](http://econsultancy.com/uk/blog/7406-waitrose-redesign-where-does-it-go-wrong)

/EDIT Just found this one too:
[Expedia on how one extra data field can cost $12m](http://www.silicon.com/management/sales-and-marketing/2010/11/01/expedia-on-how-one-extra-data-field-can-cost-12m-39746554/)